# How to map (using AutoMapper) a list in a many to many entity

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, automapper

I want to map `ProjectDto` object to `Project` object.

So, `ProjectDto` class contains list of styles:

```
public class ProjectDto
{
    public List<StyleDto>? Styles { get; set; }
    // and other properties...
}
```

And it's a `Project` class:

```
public class Project
{
    public virtual IEnumerable<StyleOfProject> StylesOfProject { get; set; }
    // and other properties...
}
```

There is many-to-many relationship between `Style` and `Project`, which is represented in `StyleOfProject` class:

```
public class StyleOfProject
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
    
    public int StyleId { get; set; }
    public virtual Style Style { get; set; }
}

public class Style
{
    public virtual IEnumerable<StyleOfProject> StyleOfProjects { get; set; }
    // and other properties...
}
```

So, I tried to map like this:

```
CreateMap<ProjectDto, Project>().ForMember(dest => dest.StylesOfProject, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Styles))
```

And I got empty `StylesOfProject`. I understand this is incorrect mapping way, but I don't have any right ideas how to map it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I found a solution to my problem:

```
CreateMap<ProjectDto, Project>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.StylesOfProject,
        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Styles))
    .AfterMap((_, dest) =>
    {
        foreach (var s in dest.StylesOfProject)
        {
            s.ProjectId = dest.Id;
            s.Project = dest;
        }
    });

CreateMap<StyleDto, StyleOfProject>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Style,
        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src))
    .AfterMap((_, dest) =>
    {
        dest.StyleId = dest.Style.Id;
    });

CreateMap<StyleDto, Style>();
```

**AfterMap()** is very useful thing in AutoMapper. You can find more information on this [website](https://docs.automapper.org/en/v8.1.0/Before-and-after-map-actions.html).